# Excel questions about group one column

Tags: excel

[image]

Hi

how to make the first ST column to only show one AL instead of a bunch of Al, and AR instead of a bunch of AR?

Comment: Have you tried a pivot table?

Comment: its not a pivot table thing. I do not want state summary. I want to keep all the rest column same, just not show every state name in front of it.

Comment: Do you want to delete the duplicated values?  If not, you could use a conditional format the set the text color to white.

Comment: Merge & Center, maybe?

Comment: Do you want to collapse the groups so that you can expand individual states with a click?

Comment: @TimWilliams, I've found that setting a custom number format of `;;;` provides more versatility than setting a white font color.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a column to the left of the table (say, column A) with this formula that you can copy down. So in A2, put

```
=if(B1=B2, "", B2)
```

and then hide column B (the original state column).

Answer (score -1):

To my mind @Tim Williams' suggestion is much the best (and Merging worth avoiding with vigour). Select A2 to end, HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=A1=A2
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select Font colour (white), <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Deleting duplicates seems to offer no significant benefit but may be regretted subsequently (for example if later sorting). Deleting values may suit since reinstating them would be easy.